# Delegate click event inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the following code from a Xamarin Project inside the `GetView` method of a custom `Adapter`:

```
var document = elementList[position].DocumentID;
view.FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.btnOpen).Click += delegate {
    OpenElement (document);
};
```

The Android `ListView` recycles the list items so it's memory efficient, I know that. However, when I click the `btnOpen`, The `OpenElement` function gets called but with the wrong `document` value (the value is the one for the first element in the `Listview`). I assume it is a weird condition given the fact that there's a delegate there and it is probably not getting the `document` value accordingly.

Is there any fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common misbehaviour. Have you previously removed / unsubscribed from the event handler before adding a new one?

You could easily create a click handler by creating a private function like this:

```
private void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var snd = ((LinearLayout) sender).Tag;
}
```

So, like Cheesebaron said, add the relevant data to the tag of the view by assigning it like `ll.Tag = document` and then, on the `HandleClick` function above, you could retrieve the proper value (don't forget to cast the result to the appropriate class).

And, to fix your problem, you'll need to, first, unsubscribe from the event handler by doing: `ll.Click -= HandleClick;` and then, add the new handler: `ll.Click += HandleClick`. So you'll be removing the first handler and adding a new one there.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to do something like:

```
var ll = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.btnOpen);
ll.Tag = position;
ll.Click += (s,e) => {
    var view = (View) sender;
    var position = (int) view.Tag;

    var document = elementList[position].DocumentID;
    OpenElement (document);
};
```

Or you would implement the ViewHolder pattern instead.

Comment: Doesn't work :( Still showing the wrong "document" :(